# how to partition the mounted drives in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, gparted, ext4, unmount

[image]

i've installed ubuntu 14.04 in single boot. My hard disk have 1tb capacity. While i'm trying to install windows in place of the ubuntu it shows no drivers are found error. So i'm decided to partotion my driver. For this i'm using gpartiotioner. But it shows that the driver could not not be mounted.I have read so many articles . But i've not get any solution for it. So plz help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this from within a running system.
You have to do the partitioning from a live media.
Boot from Ubuntu (DVD/USB) installation media.
Select Try Ubuntu without installing.
On the Live desktop open GParted ...

Comment: ok..thanks for the info.I'm new to using linux.So  I need some steps to do the partitioning from live media.

Comment: ok.. I don't know about live media :-( . So help how to go through this?

Comment: ohhh..kk but when i'm instaling windows it is not ask for any partitions is just shows an error message likw drivers are not found